# Handle large point layer on client side using Leaflet/OpenLayers

Tags: leaflet, javascript, openlayers, geojson

I'm planning to write an web app which will display large amount of point features (approx. 120 000 features, 50mb after data cleanup). Each point will consist of only two values - coordinates and name. What are the options to store and serve these points for client side? It is impossible of course to store such large GeoJSON on client side.

I will need also possibility of filtering the data. How to handle such large set of data with Leaflet or OpenLayers?

Comment: It is of course not *impossible*, just *impracticable*. Please ask only one question per Question.

Answer (score 1):

You could store 120,000 points in a PostGIS database and serve them with GeoServer using OpenLayers or Leaflet.

To improve performance you could [create rules in an SLD](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/ysld/reference/scalezoom.html) to filter which points are displayed at which scales.

You could also use a [CQL Filter](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html) to allow the end user to manually filter which points are displayed.